# How can I generate rectangle style edges instead of curves in GraphViz?

Tags: python, graph-theory, graphviz, edge-list

I have generated Graphviz images with the dot language using the Pydot Python library.

[image: Generated Graphviz Graph]

But the edges are getting draw in curves, and I need this kind of output:

[image: Expected Graphviz]

Please provide a solution using Graphviz.

Answer (score 39):

This feature is called "[orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality) edge routing" and is available in Graphviz versions from September 28, 2010 and newer. Use "graph [splines=ortho]"; see the [Graphviz documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dsplines).

```
digraph Orthogonal {
  graph [label="Orthogonal edges", splines=ortho, nodesep=0.8]
  node [shape=box]
  a->{b c}
  b->{d e}
  c->{f g}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Triend your way, here's the output:[Output Image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/yatinkumbhare/6999721661/), but library not able to plot edges head over the port attribute.

Comment: Yes, I see the same problem - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979094