# strictly left to right orthogonal arcs in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

This question is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74970233) question.

In addition to strictly east-to-west arcs, I would also like them to be orthogonal (ie not curved.) So I added the attribute "splines=ortho" to the dot file, like this:

```
digraph net {
    graph [splines=ortho]
    "C0" [shape=oval label="C0"]
    "C1" [shape=oval label="C1"]
    "B0" [shape=box label="B0"]
    rankdir="LR"
    "C0":e -> "B0":w
    "B0":e -> "C1":w
    "C1":e -> "B0":w
}
```

Now I am getting this image, where the arcs are going **through** the nodes:

[image]

Is it possible to get a picture like this, where the orthogonal arc moves **around** the nodes, something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you have to DIY.  Here we add lots of invisible nodes and then "connect the dots" (puns!).
Note the use of **dir** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/dir/), **headclip** (http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/headclip/), and **tailclip** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/tailclip/) attributes.

```
digraph net {
    graph [splines=false]
//    rankdir="LR"  << turned it off, makes things easier?
    graph [nodesep=.07]

    {
      node [style=invis label=""]
      I1 I2 I3  I4 I5 I6   X2 X4 X6
    }
    {rank=same I1 I2 I3  I4 I5 I6}
    {rank=same C0 B0 C1  X2 X4 X6}
    
    "C0"   [shape=oval label="C0"]
    "C1"   [shape=oval label="C1"]
    "B0"   [shape=box  label="B0"]
    
    C0 -> X2 [dir=none headclip=false]
    X2 -> B0 [tailclip=false]
    B0 -> X4 [dir=none headclip=false]
    X4 -> C1 [tailclip=false]
    C1 -> X6 [dir=none headclip=false]
    {
      edge [dir=none tailclip=false headclip=false]
      I6 -> X6
      I2 ->I3 ->I4 ->  I5 ->I6
    }
    I2 -> X2 [tailclip=false headclip=false]
}
```

Giving:
[image]